# How to print my array after a string horizontally?

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

There is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   int i;
    int[] numbers= new int[5]; 

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("Insert 5 numbers:");
        numeros[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Array.Sort(numeros);
        Console.WriteLine("Ascendant numbers {0}",numbers[i]);
        Array.Reverse(numbers);              
        Console.WriteLine("Descendant numbers {0}", numbers[i]);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

So at this moment for each loop my app prints my string per item of my array, followed by the number.

What I want is, to print the string only once,  followed by the complete array in a single line.

Comment: use string.Join - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Have you tried the `Console.Write` method? BTW: No need to Sort and Reverse in the loop.  You will get the same result no matter how many times you do it...:)

Comment: I try `String.Join`... but it only no prints my String `Console.WriteLine(string.Join("Numeros ingresados de forma ascendente {0}",numeros [i]))`

Comment: `Console.Write` method no print my string too

Comment: @GerardoVentas OK, lets take our crytall ball and try to see why it doesn't work.....

Comment: @GerardoVentas Console.WriteLine("Numbers :"+string.Join(" ",numeros));

Comment: _[Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the **desired behavior**, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)_

Comment: Sorry @Eser .. I try again... and  `Console.Write` it prints my string, but is the same as `Console.WriteLine` because it still prints my strings each loop

Comment: @GerardoVentas  `I try String.Join... but it only no prints my String` Maybe you use the the tools wrong :)  `Console.WriteLine("Ascendant numbers:" + string.Join(", ", numbers.OrderBy(x => x)));`

Answer (score 2):

You can (1) Sort and reverse only once (2) Print the string outside the loop (3) Print only the digit inside loop (4) use `Console.Write` to print digits in the same line. Something like

```
Array.Sort(numeros);
Console.WriteLine("Numeros ingresados de forma ascendente  :");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Console.Write("{0} ", numeros[i]);

}

Array.Reverse(numeros); 
Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Numeros ordenados de forma descendente :");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Console.Write("{0} ", numeros[i]);
}
```

N.B. I do not understand the language you are printing, so not sure the meaning remains same after code change.

Comment: @GerardoVentas no problem, glad that it worked. But, more important is for you to understand why your code was not working as you expected.